# ASP.NET MVC n-Tier Code First Migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using n-tier architecture for my web application and DbContext class is here

```
public class Db:DbContext
{
    public Db()
        : base("DbConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Db>(null);
    }
    public class DbInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Db>
    {
        protected override void Seed(Db context)
        {


        }
    }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {


        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(r => r.Roles).WithMany(o => o.Users).Map(f =>
        {
            f.MapLeftKey("UserId");
            f.MapRightKey("RoleId");
        });


        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

My app.config file is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbConnectionString" connectionString="Server=xx.xxx.xx.xxx;Database=gonulluh_first;User Id=*******;Password=*******;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="Data.Db, Data">
        <databaseInitializer type="DbInitializer, Data" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Data.DbContextFactory, EntityFramework">      
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

When I use "update-database -verbose" command in package manager console it migrate my db to local db.

```
Using StartUp project 'Web'.
Using NuGet project 'Data'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'DbConnectionString' (DataSource: (localdb)\v11.0, Provider:         System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention).
No pending explicit migrations.
Running Seed method.
```

Do you know why I cannot update remote database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer but it does not solve my issue.

I am using n-tier like below

--Core
--Data
--Infra
--Service
--Web

All problem was in my web.config file in Web project. I have configured it like below and problem solved.

```
<entityFramework>
  <contexts>
    <context type="Data.Db, Data">
      <databaseInitializer type="Data.DbInitializer, Data" />
    </context>
  </contexts>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="Data.DbContextFactory, Data">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="v11.0" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you nentioned n-tier, I'm assuming your config file is in another assembly than the context (which `Update-Database` won't pick up on).

If you need to target a different server, try specifying the `-ConnectionString` argument to `Update-Database`. e.g.

```
Update-Database -ConnectionString "Server=xx.xxx.xx.xxx;Database=gonulluh_first;User Id=*******;Password=*******;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" -Verbose
```

It may prompt you for the provider, just supply `System.Data.SqlClient`.